# Nvidia ppa driver on Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 20.04

Yesterday I've upgraded my system to Ubuntu 19.10. When the system booted for the first time the screen resolution was off so I installed the nvidia drivers with the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

The drivers seems not to work as the screen glitches and eventually the system crash. 
My video card is a Nvidia GeForce 210.

If I launch the ubuntu-drivers devices, this is the output:

```
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.1/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00000A65sv00000000sd00000000bc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GT218 [GeForce 210]
driver   : nvidia-340 - third-party free recommended
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
```

Do you know why the open driver does not appear in the list? 
How can I fix the glitches? Thanks